# Philips Hue Bridge resets to factory default after power loss

Tags: philips-hue, bridge

My problem is the following: I've set up my Philips Hue Bridge and everything works great.

After a power failure, the bridge comes back to life but it appears to be reset to factory default settings.
I also receive an email from meethue.com: "your bridge has been un-linked because it has been reset to the default factory settings".

This is annoying because it means I have to re-configure all my lights and scenes and everything. Is there a way to prevent this behaviour?

PS - Power failure does not happen often in my area (although it can happen), recently I have been doing some home renovation and electrical work which means I have to manually cut the power while I'm working. It's still kind of annoying having to reconfigure everything.

This is the only drawback that I can find with the hue platform so far, everything else is great!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I have the exact same problem with my hue bridge! Is this considered normal?! I’m thinking of hooking the bridge to a UPS, by still it seems childish from a product development perspective not to think about these issues...

Comment: It's a faulty unit. What supposes to happen is that all the lights go on (pretty annoying), but not a reset of the hub.

Comment: Did you try contacting the manufacturer?

Comment: I know this is old, but it just happened to me. I got the email that said it has been reset to factory settings.  However, when I turned the bridge off and on one more time, it came back and I was able to see it in my hue app.  I did have to relink it to authorize out-of-home privileges, but I didn't have to reconfigure any of the lights, etc.

Comment: Just happened to me - can confirm reboot of the Hue Bridge caused it to reconnect fully intact.